# Tomcat exploding war, but not deploying

Tags: java, tomcat, centos, tcserver

I am using tcServer (Tomcat 7 wrapper) to deploy a war file. I have successfully deployed the war file on machine A. Machine A runs on an older version of centOS and java, and the war is deployed fine. When I try to deploy the war (exact same dist. of tcserver/tomcat) on Machine B, which runs a newer jdk and CentOS version, the war does get exploded by tomcat, and the catalina.out file shows that the server started up fine, however after that nothing happens. I use logback for logging and none of the logs are showing up.

Catalina.out:

```
Jun 29, 2015 6:02:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1755 ms
```

I am unable to make any http requests to the server either. I am using the exact same server.xml/context.xml files on both Machines, and the resources on Machine B are invalid (Machine B does not have access to them). Could this behavior be caused by this? What else could the issue be?

Comment: tomcat's server log should give you an indication of why this application is not UP.

Comment: have you checked which port the server runs on ? Perhaps it is different from what you expect. And try to deploy the manager.war from Tomcat to have a known working war file

Comment: I have verified and they both run on 8080 (as expected). The war file is identical on both boxes and known to be working.

Catalina.out output is displayed, and it appears as if it is not even attempting to deploy the war. We are using logback for logging and the logback file is not even created on machine B, as it is on A right after server startup.

Comment: but did you check the server logs directly? - logback is fine but if the application is not deploying, the logback logs are not going to get started (assuming you got it configured by your application)

Comment: Thought you were referring to catalina.out, was not aware there would be more logs to see; and yes you are right about the logback logs not getting started.I am looking around to see what I can find.

Comment: check <catalina_home>/logs - also, is the WAR file compiled for the correct JDK level (i.e. java 6, 7, 8 , etc.) - it could be simply a wrong java version of the webapp not compiled/compatible for the new JDK on the new server